# Adding supervisor to thesis

Tags: thesis

I am writing some thesis in Latex and I use some template. At the first page I would like to add my supervisor. In one file there is possibility to add it. There is macro like: \college{}; \author{}; \title{}, but there are no for supervisor something like: "\supervisor{}". Do you know what macro I can use to add supervisor? Thanks.

I am using this template:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwyOySLlDTB_a3R5aFZQNzVFRG8/edit?usp=sharing

There is the file "thesis-info.tex", where I can define \college{}; \author{}; \title{}, etc., but I don't know how to add supervisor...?

Comment: Unfortunately we aren't able to read minds ;) Which template do you use? Please provide us with an [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so that we can help you.

Comment: I added link to latex template.

Comment: Thank you! It would be good, if you could also provide a [*minimal* working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as this leaves still a lot of effort to the community. Have a look into your `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` whithin the `Macro Definitions` and `Title Page` (`\renewcommand{\maketitle}`), there you should be able to define your `\supervisor{}` via copy&paste&rename.

Comment: Please, edit the question or close it because the link to drive is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt and works. Please follow the following steps to establish a working directory.

1. Download all the template into a directory and save the `testfile.tex` shown below into the same directory.
2. Open up  the class file `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls` (a new *.cls name is preferred.)
3. Add the following lines to line 500 (right after the macro `degree`) in the -- macro definition section.

   `\newcommand{\@supervisor}{}
   \newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@supervisor}{#1}}`
4. Also insert following lines to line 575 (right after the `author` position) in the -- title page section (maketitle).

   `{\Large \bfseries{\@supervisor} \par}
    \vspace*{1ex}`
5. Compile textfile.tex

[image]

Code: testfile.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\input{preamble}

% Terms from macro definition
\title{A Test on How to Add Supervisor}
\degreedate{2014}
\degree{master}
\dept{Electrical Engineering}
\college{Engineering}
\university{ABC}
\author{Candidate Author}
\supervisor{Prof. A.B. Supervisor}
\crest{\includegraphics{University_Crest}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\include{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why there are `\@supervisor` _and_ `\supervisor`? What do both definitions do?