# Designing Latex title page for Bachelor Thesis

Tags: titles

I'm completely new to Latex and would like to design a title page for my Bachelor thesis. 
After some research, I've found a title page layout in another post here that I would love to use:

[Adding supervisor to thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196629/adding-supervisor-to-thesis#196650)

Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement it in Latex and don't understand the instructions given in the other post. I would be grateful for any help!

Currently, this is my preamble and start:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}} 
% default for 3rd arg: 2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure % as in article.cls
\makeatother

%define the author
\author{John Smith}

%define the title
\title{Blue Elephants}

\begin{document}

%omits page number
\pagenumbering{gobble}


%generates the title
\maketitle

\newpage
\end{document}
```

My existing code is mostly copy and pasted from this website to get my thesis layout to work. It's just the title page that I'm having issues with.

This is my first post. I hope I respected any potential rules.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure to write a thesis with the article class?

Answer (score 0):

Please, note that this is not an answer, is just a tip to let you go started with the definition of your title page.

The page that you provided has a broken link to google drive so I don't what layout you prefer. In the following I just added the standard definition of a title page with a supervisor.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author\\
        \supervisor%
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}} 
% default for 3rd arg: 2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure % as in article.cls
\makeatother

%define the author
\author{John Smith}

%define the title
\title{Blue Elephants}

%define the supervisor
\def\supervisor{John Doe}

\begin{document}

%omits page number
\pagenumbering{gobble}


%generates the title
\maketitle

\newpage
\end{document}
```

Here the result.

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! Adding the supervisor definitely helps. I am aware of the broken link in the question of the provided page. The answer, however, has an example of a title page that I would like to use.  Thanks again

Comment: @Mazur Glad that it could help. If you want any advice for the title page just edit your question adding more infos. If you have troubles with other things, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `titlepage` environment:

```
...
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vfill
\begin{Large}University...{Large}
\vfill
\begin{large}Faculty...\end{large}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}
\vfill
\begin{large}\begin{czech}\textbf{Your Name}\end{czech}\end{large}
\vfill
\begin{huge}My thesis...\end{huge}
\vfill
\begin{large}Bachelor thesis\end{large}
\vfill
\textbf{Supervisor...}\\
\vfill
City, 2018
\vfill
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
...
% Rest of the document
```

Basically, You use the above code instead of `\maketitle` command. Alter it as You like.

Comment: While `\begin{large}...\end{large}` may work, it is not considered best practice: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7312/35864. It is also a good idea to end the paragraph with the changed font size still active, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48741/35864.