# Custom title page for thesis with new fields (institute, supervisor)

Tags: macros, titles, thesis

Sorry, this has probably been tried more than once, but I ended up with the following broken code below.

Briefly, I attempted to:

1. define a `\institute` and `\supervisor` command;
2. redefine the `\maketitle` command (taking into account the provided institute/supervisor).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}  % background figure on title page

% copied from Pandoc default template
\providecommand{\institute}[1]{}

\makeatletter
% copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196650/95423
\newcommand{\@supervisor}{}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@supervisor}{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{The Limits of Individual Plasticity}
\author{Edward \textsc{Prendick}}
\institute{Island of Doctor Moreau}
\supervisor{Dr. \textsc{Moreau}}
\date{1896}

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
\begin{titlepage}%
    \begin{center}%
    \ThisULCornerWallPaper{0.2}{logo-univ}\par
    \vspace*{2.5cm}

    \huge\@title

    \vspace{1.5cm}

    \Large\@author

    \vspace{1.5cm}

    \normalsize
    A thesis for the degree of PhD

    \vfill

    \normalsize
    Supervised by:\\
    \@supervisor\\

    \vspace{0.8cm}
   %\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{logo/logo-lab}

    \normalsize
    \@institute

    \@date

    \end{center}%
\end{titlepage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Would anyone tell me why it fails with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\maketitle ...} \par \par \normalsize \@institute 
                                                  \par \@date \par \end {cen...
l.58 \maketitle

?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line is to use the `demo` option for`graphicx`. You should remove it.

Also, it is preferable to avoid the use of `\def` in favor of `\newcommand`.

The main problem was in `\providecommand{\institute}[1]{}`
, which you already have redefined by yourself.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}  % background figure on title page

\makeatletter
% copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196650/95423
\newcommand{\@supervisor}{}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@supervisor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@institute}{}
\newcommand{\institute}[1]{\renewcommand{\@institute}{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{The Limits of Individual Plasticity}
\author{Edward \textsc{Prendick}}
\institute{Island of Doctor Moreau}
\supervisor{Dr. \textsc{Moreau}}
\date{1896}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
        \ThisULCornerWallPaper{0.2}{pippo}\par
        \vspace*{2.5cm}

        \huge\@title\\
        \vspace{1.5cm}
        \Large\@author
        \vspace{1.5cm}

        \normalsize
        A thesis for the degree of PhD

        \vfill

        \normalsize
        Supervised by:\\
        \@supervisor

        \vspace{0.8cm}
        \includegraphics{pippo}

        \normalsize
        \@institute

        \@date

        \end{center}%
    \end{titlepage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I was missing the `\par`! Could you tell me why we need the two newcommand, first `\@supervisor`, then `\supervisor`?

Comment: because it's the second `newcommand` that redefines `\@supervisor` to expand to the argument given to `\supervisor`

Comment: And about the "institute", in pandoc they only define `\institute` (as in my question). Does it mean that the document class handles it natively? For example I think it works for beamer.

Comment: Probably. `\providecommand` defines a new command if it isn't already defined

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it. I need to get some knowledge about how to write those macros:

in the `\def` block, there should be no blanklines (probably no newlines as well):

So I replaced those newlines with `\par%`, and it works (`\maketitle` gets defined!).

For the record, there are good explanations about paragraphs in macros here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1057/95423

Corrected preamble lines:

```
\makeatletter
% copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196650/95423
\newcommand{\@institute}{}
\newcommand{\institute}[1]{\renewcommand{\@institute}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@supervisor}{}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@supervisor}{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{The Limits of Individual Plasticity}
\author{Edward \textsc{Prendick}}
\institute{Island of Doctor Moreau}
\supervisor{Dr. \textsc{Moreau}}
\date{1896}

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
\begin{titlepage}%
    \begin{center}%
    \ThisULCornerWallPaper{0.2}{logo-univ}\par%
    \vspace*{2.5cm}\par%
    \huge\@title\par%
    \vspace{1.5cm}\par%
    \Large\@author\par%
    \vspace{1.5cm}\par%
    \normalsize%
    A thesis for the degree of PhD\par%
    \vfill\par%
    \normalsize%
    Supervised by:\par\@supervisor\par%
    \vspace{0.8cm}\par%
    %\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{logo/logo-lab}\par%   
    \normalsize%
    \@institute\par%
    \@date\par%
    \end{center}%
\end{titlepage}%
}
\makeatother
```

I still need to figure out the magic behind the newcommand syntax with `\@supervisor` and `\supervisor`, but at least it works...

Comment: you can actually use ``\\`` btw

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907